# Segmentation fault while loading library with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, c, compilation, dynamic-linking, dynamic-compilation

i am facing GLIBC compatibility issues with newer version gcc 12.2

Log:-

```
/home/linux/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /home/linux/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1)
```

dynamic dependency info:-

```
ldd /home/linux/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd77bc4000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fef54267000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fef53ec9000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef53ad8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fef5446b000)
```

As per the log , i understood that minimum glibc version required for gcc 12.2 is `GLIBC 2.25`. But on my host i have `GLIBC` version as 2.23 as follows:-

```
/home/kumpt/test/sw% /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) stable release version 2.23, by Roland McGrath et al
```

I have `libc.so.6` library with `GLIBC 2.27` version at path :- `/home/kumpt/targets/lib64/libc.so.6`

I try to load the path via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /home/kumpt/targets/lib64/libc.so.6` to load the compatible library first to make `cc1` to work.

But i am facing `segmentation fault` issue , While running `cc1`

```
ldd /home/linux/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1
Segmentation fault
```

`cc1` and `libc.so.6` both are based out of 64-bit arch:-

```
file /home/linux/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1
   /home/linux/x86_64/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0/12.2.0/cc1 : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

file /home/kumpt/targets/lib64/libc.so.6
/home/kumpt/targets/lib64/libc.so.6:ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Why am i hitting into `Segmentation fault` issue. How can i workaround this ? Please advice.

Comment: You cannot stick a newer version of `libc.so.6` in somewhere and hope your system will keep working. If you have a library that requires a newer glibc than what's installed on your system, you have two choices: (1) rebuild the library locally from sources or (2) upgrade your OS.

Comment: Upgrading os is not possible in my case, Why do i need to rebuild the library locally if i already have dynamic library libc.so.6 available on the host?

Comment: Because having libc.so.6 **does not work**. It was never supposed or intended to work. `libc.so.6` is a **part of** glibc, and glibc **is your OS**. It must be upgraded as a whole, or not at all.

Comment: Ok.. **glibc is your OS** ?  I Dont get it. Could you please elaborate?  Also what is the exact reason with seg fault issue?

Comment: Quote: "These libraries provide critical APIs including ISO C11, POSIX.1-2008, BSD, OS-specific APIs and more". That's your OS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/775806